# Is there a way in Google forms to make automatic, time-based submissions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

It's been a while since I have been using Google Forms to have some control of my personal expenses. The thing is that I have recurring payments each month too and I was wondering whether you know of any script that can be tweaked and later be attached to my form, perhaps via the spreadsheet whether the responses are collected, that submits a predefined set of entries at a certain date each month.
I am aware that we could run a script directly on the spreadsheet simulating a form submission but then I guess there would be inconsistencies between the responses stored in the form and data in the responses tab.
So, is it possible?
If not, what would you suggest?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot perform a Google Form Submission with a time based trigger.   The form must be opened and submitted by a user.  You could use the onFormSubmit trigger to perform additional automation during each submission.  If you need more information please be a little more precise in your question  because it's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: _but then I guess there would be inconsistencies between the responses stored in the form and data in the responses tab._ The key question is "which is the data set that you rely on from day-to-day"? Is it the form and or the spreadsheet (that you might massage to generate a budget forecast. If it is the spreadsheet, and if you have some non-form transactions, then so-what? This is what @Cooper is getting at when he said "please be [...] more precise".

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that Forms does not allow automatic time based submissions, otherwise it could become chaos in Google's Servers. So I guess the idea is just to automatically add a line in the responses tab, say every 1st of the month. I guess this can be done with Time Based Triggers on a specific script. What I don't know is how to add a line in the responses tab trough scripting. As an example, we could make a script emulating a form with two generic questions. The script should locate the column for each question, add a timestamp and add the predefined answer for each question.

Comment: You could make automatic time based submission with an html form.  We call that a web app